# Getting multiple sinosidual waves using Fourier Transform Python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, fft

According to  http://www.thefouriertransform.com/

" The Fourier Transform shows that any waveform can be re-written as the sum of sinusoidal functions. "

I have some signals (each have shape of 256,64) that I want to break down into sub-signals and I want to use those sub-signals then to generate the real signal back. I am doing it right now like this:-

```
#getting data
with open('../f', 'rb') as fp:
    f=pickle.load(fp)

from scipy.fftpack import fft, dct

f=f[0]

tf=fft(f)

x=np.reshape(np.abs(tf),(256,64))

plt.plot(x)

plt.show()

print(x.shape)    #same shape as f
```

But I am getting output in the same shape as of the real signal but with some imaginary values which are discarded ultimately. I have looked at other Fourier questions here but none of them gave satisfying result, they just transformed the input signal. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: when you start with a curve in the time domain then apply fft its then in the frequency domain where each frequency has a magnitude and phase ... to transform this freq domain back into the time domain, to re-create the original source curve, you need to perform an inverse fft which I am not seeing in your code ... its enlightening to write this ifft yourself from scratch however python has such an ifft api call

Comment: I used ifft but it will simply convert x back to f. But how can I get those features or sub-signals that fourier transform outputs? Or how can I visualize them like plot them etc?

Answer (score 1):

To see the sinusoidal components, you need to plot sine waves.

```
x = a * sin(t)
```

not a reshaped FFT result.

If you don't care about phase, the number of sinewave plots will be half the length of your FFT + 1, which each sinewave of a frequency calculated from the bin center of each FFT result element (index times samplerate divided by length), and its amplitude given by the abs() of the FFT bin.

Comment: I am quite naive with fft, can you please provide a minimal example from my given code? Where is fft being used to decompose in sin waves? Pardon me for asking this question but I really want to know this.